# Observing Store State Changes in Middleware

Tags: redux

I'm writing a piece of Redux Middleware which is responsbile for adding the user's OAuth AccessToken to `API_CALL` cations before they hit the [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware).

```
// sign appends the `Authorization` HTTP Header to an API_CALL action
function sign(action) {
    action[CALL_API].headers = {
        ...action[CALL_API].headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getState()auth.accessToken}`;
    }
}

// Redux middleware signature.
return ({dispatch, getState}) => {
    return next => action => {
        if (action[CALL_API]) {
            sign(action);
        }
        return next(action);
    }
}
```

However, I also want this middleware to detect when the User's AccesToken has expired...

```
function tokenExpired() {
    return (Date.now() > getState().auth.expirationTime);
}
```

When this happens, the middleware detains the action (prevents it from being passed to the `next` middleware in the chain) and stores it in an internal list.  It then kicks off the async. Token refresh process by dispatching a 'refresh access token' FSA:

```
if (tokenExpired()) {
    // detainActions is an array, declared outside 
    // of the middleware's scope.
    detainActions.push(action);
    dispatch(refreshAccessToken());
}
else {
    next(sign(action));
}
```

Finally, I want to listen for when the 'refresh access token' flow has completed and flush (re-dispatch) all detained actions.  Currently I am doing this by looking out for `AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE` FSA's as they flow through my middleware (the `AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE` action is dispatched as as side-effect of the `refreshAccessToken` thunk.

```
// Redux middleware signature.
return ({dispatch, getState}) => {
    return next => action => {

        if (action.type === AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE && !action.error) {
            // Let the AuthResponse action pass to the store.
            next(action);

            // Flush detained actions now we have a new grant.
            return flushAndRedispatchDetainedActions(dispatch);
        }
        else {
            // Sign CALL_API requests logic as above.
        }
    }
}
```

However I am not happy with this approach as there is no certainty that the `AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE` FSA will actually hit the reducers (it may be intercepted by other middleware, or be further defered).

Possible alternative approaches I have considered are having the `refreshAccessToken` actionCreator return a thunk which returns a Promise; that way my middleware can wait for that promise to resolve before flushing and replaying all requests, ie:

```
if (tokenExpired()) {
    // refreshAccessToken thunk returns a Promise. 
    dispatch(refreshAccessToken());
        .then(flushAndRedispatchDetainedActions();
}
```

Or alternativley I could have my middleware observe the store directly and trigger an action when the `auth.accessToken` value changes - however, I'm not clear on what the guidance is for middleware observing the store (I'm guessing it's not possible as middleware needs to be instantiated before the final store object is created.)

Thanks :)

#### Update

Thinking about the problem on the way home; if I were to move the actual authentication logic out of `refreshAccessToken` (a thunk'd action creator), and into the middleware itself then I would save a lot of pain:

```
// Redux middleware signature.
return ({dispatch, getState}) => {
    return next => action => {
        if (action[CALL_AUTH]) {
            authHelper.refreshGrant()
                .then(grant => dispatch(processGrant(newGrant));
        }
        else {
            // Sign CALL_API requests logic as above.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up creating a store enhancer for tagging actions with side-effects which are executed after the action has been reduced: https://github.com/jonnyreeves/redux-action-side-effects

Comment: Can it be done like this? https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware/issues/21#issuecomment-183439582